# Login Form is not connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I tried out this tutorial [here](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/11/ajax-login-script-with-jquery-php-mysql.html) and my problem is that I can't login with an Account.
I created a record in my database (username, password etc.) and tried to log in but it didn't work.

I am kind of worried about that part here that it may be outdated:

```
<?php
 $db_host = "localhost";
 $db_name = "dbregistration";
 $db_user = "root";
 $db_pass = "";
 
 try{
  
  $db_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_pass);
  $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 }
 catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
 }
?>
```

Just because there is still MySQL instead of mysqli...
Could that be the problem?
I neither have any logs nor errors and my provider is [Nitrado](https://server.nitrado.net/).

Comment: `PDO` or `mysqli_` aren't outdated, `mysql_` is. What you can do to see if it makes a connection is by simply adding `if(!$db_con) {//error message}`. Also can you add the login functionality as well

Comment: The mysql-bit you see in the PDO connection has nothing to do with mysql_ - it's just to show PDO what type of database you're connecting to / which internal DB-connection it should utilize. Since PDO can connect to pretty much any type of DB that PHP can connect to, differentiating which one you're using can be important. So no, that has nothing to do with it, and what you have there is not outdated.

Comment: what kind of error u are getting?